# swift dictionary in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I has add struct

```
struct lists {
    var title : String!
    var description : String!
}
```

create dictionary:

```
var list = Dictionary<String, String>()
var listArray = [lists]()
```

update data to dictionary:

```
list.updateValue("InquiryNumberCode", forKey: InquiryNumberCode)
list.updateValue("InquiryNumberDescription", forKey: InquiryNumberDescription)
list.updateValue("InquiryNumberValue", forKey: InquiryNumberValue)
```

run for loop to append listArray:

```
for (description, title) in list {
    print("\(title): \(description)")
    listArray.append(lists(title: title , description: description ))
}
```

Tried insert data to Tableview cell has same error.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detail", for: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell
    let celldata = listArray[indexPath.section]
    cell.titleOutlet.text = celldata.title[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Character' to type 'String?'

I can't transfer data to Tableview cell, have any one can told me why?

Comment: For a table view with multiple sections each with multiple rows you need an array of arrays.

Comment: @rmaddy not true ,  do you have a statement from Apple that using dictionary is not valid with tableView , it's not because the data is unsorted , what if the op doesn't care about that

Comment: @Sh_Khan You need to access a specific value based on the section or row. Dictionaries are not accessed by index. Dictionaries have no order.

Comment: keys can be used to handle that

Comment: `celldata.title` is a String, so `celldata.title[indexPath.row]` is a Character. Hence the error. Maybe you meant `celldata[indexPath.row].title` ?

Comment: @Koen but unlabeled only support string value right

Comment: tried add `cell.titleOutlet.text = celldata[indexPath.row].title` but response error : Type 'lists' has no subscript members

Comment: Try it without the subscript: `cell.titleOutlet.text = celldata.title` But then you won't be using your `list` dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listArray` is an Array of `lists` structs. So to access `title`, you should change your code to:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detail", for: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell
    let celldata = listArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleOutlet.text = celldata.title

    return cell
}
```

Comment: tried `let celldata = listArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleOutlet.text = celldata.title` but response Error :Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: Sorry, is work now, I has change some code, change `numberOfRowsInSection section` return `listArray.count`, Tableview cell can insert my array data, thank you guys.